# Regarding the creation and destruction of sensitive data on linux/unix systems

Tags: linux, tmpfs, ramdisk, data-destruction

In modern file systems (and on modern SSDs) there is no guarantee that if you write over a file using a traditional utility (such as dd) that the data will be overwritten in-place and journaled backups destroyed.  As a result, the data could possibly be recovered.  So, after a little research I figured that mounting a temporary ramfs (tmpfs was ruled out due to the potential for it to swap) would be the way to go:

```
# mkdir -p /mnt/tmp/ram
# mount -t ramfs -o size=[size, but ramfs grows as needed] ramfs /mnt/tmp/ram
# [create the sensitive data, secure it, copy out secured data]
# umount /mnt/tmp/ram
```

Q1: Does unmounting a ramfs destroy the data contained within it?

Q2: If the data is not guaranteed to be destroyed, is there any feasible way to recover said data (or am I just being paranoid)?

Q3: If the data is recoverable, would

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/tmp/ram/[filename]
```

destroy the data properly or is ramfs not guaranteed to overwrite files in-place?

Constraints: The system *cannot be forced to reboot* before/during/after these operations.

In case you're curious, the "sensitive data" in this case is the unsalted, unhashed usernames+passwords for a pam database.  The "secured data" is the salted/hashed database, which would end up on the primary drive.  I do not want the sensitive data to touch the drive (as I am using ext3 - which cannot guarantee the data will be unrecoverable without wiping the entire partition as far as I understand).

If you know a better way to go about doing this, please enlighten me, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Q1: Yes

Q2: It is not feasible to recover the data. Nevertheless, if you want to be extreme you could do it like this :)

1. Create some space in ram:

   `mkdir ram
   mount -t ramfs -o size=1000M ramfs ram/`
2. Create some randomly filled file which we encrypt in that RAM space. Being filled with random data it will be impossible to establish boundaries between random and encrypted data.

   `dd if=/dev/urandom of=ram/test bs=1M count=512`
3. Setup encription

   `cryptsetup -y luksFormat ram/test
   cryptsetup luksOpen ram/test encypted`
4. Format and mount the new secure space:

   `mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/encypted
   mkdir securedir
   mount /dev/mapper/encypted securedir/`
5. Umont securedir/ and then ram/ to loose the data until the end of time.

   `umount securedir/
   umount ram/`

Comment: Worked well enough, walking the ram location immediately after showed nothing but garbage, +1 and accepted answer.